# Guardar imagen generada con textPainter en PHP

Tags: php

Hola buenas tardes estoy intentando guardar una imagen que la he generado con PHP usando la clase [`textPainter`](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/PHP-Backend/tree/master/textPainter) pero la siguiente función no me resulta:

```
imagepng( $img, 'test/imagen.png' );
```

Éste es mi código, espero me puedan dar una orientación:

```
<?php
require_once 'class.textPainter.php';
$x = "470";
$y = "80";
$R = "0";
$G = "0";
$B = "0";
$size = "50";
$texto = $_GET["texto"];
//crea la imagen con el nombre recibido por metodo GET
$img = new textPainter('./game.jpg', $texto, 'C:\xampp\htdocs\game\arial.ttf', $size);

if(!empty($x) && !empty($y)){
    $img->setPosition($x, $y);
}

if(!empty($R) && !empty($G) && !empty($B)){
    $img->setTextColor($R,$G,$B);
}
$img->show(); // muestra la imagen final
// Ahora la quiero guardar mero no me resulta con imagepng( $img, 'test/imagen.png' ); 
?>
```

Comment: que error da? esa es la forma, hay permisos de escritura? conviene mas ponerle un path absoluto onda `imagepng( $img, __DIR__. '/test/imagen.png' ); ` eso graba en la carpeta test que esta justo en la carpeta donde está el php

Comment: Que error da? Si, te genera la imagen, solo deberias forzar la descarga?
como lo muestran aqui:
http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/forzar-descargas-con-php-c166l/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma correcta de hacer el volcado (si la propiedad fuera pública):

```
imagepng( $img->img, 'test/imagen.png' );
```

El problema es que, como puedes ver en el código fuente de la clase, [dicha propiedad es privada](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/PHP-Backend/blob/master/textPainter/class.textPainter.php#L16) y, por lo tanto, no es accesible desde tu código:

```
<?php
class textPainter{
    private $img;
/* ... */
```

Una posible solución (sin alterar la clase original), podría ser usar `ob_start()` para guardar la salida en el búfer y posteriormente `ob_get_contents()` para guardar la imagen guardada en el búfer (sin vaciarlo) en un archivo:

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once 'class.textPainter.php';
$x = "470";
$y = "80";
$R = "0";
$G = "0";
$B = "0";
$size = "50";
$texto = $_GET["texto"];
//crea la imagen con el nombre recibido por metodo GET
$img = new textPainter(
  './game.jpg',
  $texto,
  'C:/xampp/htdocs/game/arial.ttf',
  $size
);

if(!empty($x) && !empty($y)) {
    $img->setPosition($x, $y);
}

if(!empty($R) && !empty($G) && !empty($B)) {
    $img->setTextColor($R,$G,$B);
}
/* Envío la imagen al búfer de salida */
$img->show();
/* Ahora guardamos la imagen en un archivo (en JPEG porque el formato
  se obtiene del archivo original) */
file_put_contents('test/imagen.jpg', ob_get_contents());
```

Otra opción sería reimplementar el método `show()` para permitir enviar la imagen a un archivo o bien un método *getter* para obtener la imagen original.

PD: No te recomiendo usar esta clase para producción, tras echar un vistazo al código he visto que no soporta herencia (agregar funcionalidad a través de `extends`) y cada vez que se llama a `show()` se vuelve a pintar el texto sobre la imagen. Tal y como está desarrollada la clase debería hacerse una única vez en el constructor y que `show()` permitiera dar salida sin modificar el contenido.

PD2: El código de la clase tiene un error en el tipo mime enviado que hace que algunos navegadores no muestren correctamente la imagen.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, resulta que usé `file_put_contents('img/imagen.jpg', ob_get_contents());` y si, me guarda la imagen pero con 0 Bytes, osea en blanco. que puede estar pasando ?

Comment: ¿Usaste `ob_start()` al principio? Si no se activa el uso del búfer éste estará vacío.

Comment: no estaba usando `ob_start()` y ahora que lo estoy usando funciona perfectamente muchas gracias.